QGIS writeAsVectorFormatV3 provides no useful errors
I am trying to write a layer as GeoPackage+symbology from my .qgz project file, which itself references the data in a PostGIS database but it is failing without any hint as to what's wrong. I've scoured the docs but they're bare-bone on examples and don't say what error code 8 means.
Anyone else successfully use writeAsVectorFormatV3 to write to a GeoPackage?
import os,sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsApplication, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

# Supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.2", True)
# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Replace these paths with your actual paths
project_path = "zoning.qgz"
layer_name = "parcel"
output_file = "parcel.gpkg"

# Load the project
project = QgsProject.instance()
print(f'Opening project {project_path}..')
project.read(project_path)

assert os.path.isfile(project_path)
print(project.mapLayersByName(layer_name))
layer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GPKG'  # Specify the GeoPackage format
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()

error  = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
            layer,
            output_file,
            transform_context,
            options
             )
if error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print('Oh an error has happened: {details}'.format(details=error))

And the output is:
Opening project zoning.qgz..
[<QgsVectorLayer: 'parcel' (postgres)>]
<class 'qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer'>
Oh an error has happened: (8, '', '', '')

Edit: Solution was that I didn't have my PostGIS database credentials embedded into my project file. My solution to avoid having my creds stored in plaintext in the project file is to dynamically set user/password into the URI in my script (which is separately loaded into my script through a password manager). My code works on QGIS 3.36.2:
layer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
...
# Get the data provider of the layer
provider = layer.dataProvider()
# Get the current data source URI
uri = provider.dataSourceUri()
# Add our database user and password to it
uri += f'user={user} password={passwd}'

# Update layer with connection details so we can grab data
layer.setDataSource(uri, layer.name(), 'postgres')

# Write layer to geopackage
...


The return value of QgsVectorFileWriter.WriteAsVectorFormatV3 is a QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError object. This is an enumerator. Therefore, you need to match the integer returned to the enumerator item to get  useful error information.

@BenW I'm kind of a bonehead with python but with that documentation I was able to figure out I could do this, which seems a little odd. Still frustrating that it doesn't give me additional info about what about the layer specifically was invalid (struggling to format this in a comment):
error[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.ErrInvalidLayer
print('invalid layer!')

Probably this link will help you: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.ErrInvalidLayer
Please check whether your layer that you're trying to export is valid. Maybe something happened with original layer's source?

I realized that I didn't have my database credentials saved and it prompted me each time I opened the file in the QGIS GUI, so clearly my code wouldn't have that auth info. I saved auth info as plaintext into the project file and that got the export working, thanks!
Not ideal though, I'm sure there's some way to pass user/pass in via pyqgis?
Also very frustrating that I don't get much more debug information on the failure besides "invalid layer".

I figured out how to set my user/password in PyQGIS, I updated my post with the new code. Thank you!

It seems the issue is that the code do not use an options.layerName = ...
In a QGIS context (did not tried from the standalone code to be fair), I've tried successfully with the following code
layer_input_name = "yourlayernameinyourproject"
layer_output_name = "desiredoutputlayername"
output_file_path = 'outfilename.gpkg'

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_input_name)[0]

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GPKG'
options.layerName = layer_output_name


write_result, error_message, new_file, new_layer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
            layer,
            output_file_path,
            QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
            options)

PS: I didn't really invent the code as I mainly borrowed code from the PyQGIS tests in QGIS source code e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsvectorfilewriter.py

I tried this and it was not the issue, rychlik helped lead me to the solution above.
